# How to show upload date fore each file

Tags: 7, files

I have a content type called 'Documents' which has 2 fields: `title` and `file`.
There can be attached multiple files the `file` field.

But how can I show the upload date for every single file?
I have tried using Views, but could only get the upload date for the first file, not the rest of the files.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it using this solution
https://www.drupal.org/node/1578484

```
function mytheme_file_formatter_table($variables) {
  $header = array(t('Attachment'), t('Size'), t('Date'));
  $rows = array();
  foreach ($variables['items'] as $delta => $item) {
    $rows[] = array(
      theme('file_link', array('file' => (object) $item)),
      format_size($item['filesize']),
      format_date($item['timestamp'], $type = 'short'),
      );
  }
  return empty($rows) ? '' : theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows));
}
```